# How to re-assign option-F3 to "application windows"

Tags: mission-control

If I assign option-F3 in the "Application Windows" select list in:

`System Preferences->Mission Control`

It seems to allow me to do that and there are no conflicts reported for the key-combo in:

`System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts`

But the next time I open `System Preferences->Mission Control`, the select list is empty.  And if I type option-F3, System Preferences launches and the mission control system preferences pane comes up.

1. Where is the option-F3 -> Mission Control Preference pane action set?
2. How do I change it so I can re-assign option-F3 to do what I want?
3. Why is there no reported conflict in the keyboard shortcuts settings when I assign option-F3?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. I pretty much just gave up using that as a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your Mac to treat the F-keys as standard function keys. To do so go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard** (not Shortcuts) and look for the option to **Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys.** Enabling that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  That does solve the problem, but it also creates new problems. I have an extended keyboard, so it does have an `fn` key, but, but that and many of the function keys are so far apart, I cannot enter them with one hand. I was able to create shortcuts to restore the original assignments such as: `F3`=MC, `F4`=Launchpad, but how can I restore the dimmer, brighter, mute, volup, and voldown function key shortcuts?

Comment: Incidentally, I used to have these combos all set up without issue. But I think the Catalina update is what may have started the problem. I just tried 2 3rd party apps and still cannot get all the function keys working like I want them.

Comment: Ok. I have a computer running Monterey and it has no problem assigning option-F3. I guess that's one more reason to update.